Passing title to svg using vite-plugin-svgr
I'm trying to pass a title to and <svg> using vite-plugin-svgr and I can't find a way to do it.
I know that the <svg> itself doesn't have a title attribute and that in order to pass title to <svg> I need to pass <title> element as the first child. What is the best way to achieve that without using ref ?
How I tried to pass the title (this doesn't work):
import { ReactComponent as Icon} from "./icon.svg";
...
return <Icon title="icon title" />

I also tried passing a <title> element using React.cloneElement() but that doesn't seem to work either:
import { ReactComponent as Icon} from "./icon.svg";
...
return cloneElement(<Icon />, undefined, <title>icon title</title>);

example:
<!-- circle.svg -->

<svg height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="45" cx="50" cy="50" fill="red" />
</svg>

// Icon.jsx
import { ReactComponent as Circle } from "./assets/circle.svg"

const Icon = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Circle title='icon title' />
        </div>
    );
};

Final DOM :
<svg height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" title="icon title">
    <circle r="45" cx="50" cy="50" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>


If you need to provide an accessible name to the icon, you can try <Icon aria-label="icon title">. But it will not influence the browser’s tooltip, if any <title> element is present already. It would be great if you could provide an interactive code sample for us to investigate.

If I’m not mistaken, above examples don’t make use of svgr at all. Apparently, this way the svg “functions as an image element […] and cannot be customized with props”. Here’s an example on how to use SVGR to import SVGs. That way, the first code sample should work.

@Andy I want to pass the title to use the browser’s tooltip.. and I don't understand what you mean by  "if any  element is present already".

The SVG file you are importing might include a title already.

I checked, it doesn't include a title.

Well it doesn’t really matter. I believe your issue lies in the second comment. Did you have a look at that?

I looked at it, to my knowledge vite-plugin-svgr uses svgr under the hood to convert svg to a react component. and it doesn't require me to use <img /> tag.

Did you check the final DOM in your browser? Please try to provide a Minimal, reproducible example in the question, so we can investigate.

I looked at the question again, and I understand that you managed to pass the title attribute down, am I right? Why do you want to pass down the <title> SVG element?

I pass the title as a prop but it doesn’t show in the final DOM render. I’m trying to pass the title so that when the user will hover over the svg the browser’s tooltip will show the title.

Thanks for the answer, but I got that. What I didn’t is that the browser (at least Firefox) doesn’t do that for the title attribute, which is surprising. I’ll leave this question to others until an interactive code sample makes it less effort to help.

The title attribute doesn’t do anything on an  element. To pass a title the first child of the  element should be a  element

Passing title is not enabled by default using vite-plugin-svgr, in order to pass the title you in the svgr config you need to set the titleProp to be true like so:
svgr({
  svgrOptions: {
    titleProp: true,
  },
});

That way when the svgr transforms the title attribute into a <title> tag.
